# Move Background as the content moves

Tags: css, background-image

OK, I would like make my "compass" move so it will not block the text when the screen gets smallar.

http://www.mateuszrybinski.com/

The point is not to make the compass go over the text.

["I’d love to travel but...
I don’t have money.
I don't have time.
I can't speak the language.
What is your excuse?"]

```
#main_box {
margin: auto;
background-color: #c95242;
overflow: auto;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-bottom: 70px;
background-image: url(http://www.mateuszrybinski.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/half.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

how can I do it? The best solution would be if the compass was going down as the text was closing in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customize the position of the compass image, I would recommend not applying it as a background image. Instead, make it show up inline so that your text will never overlap it, similar to what you've done with your portrait image.

That being said, I'm not totally sure where you want your image to show up and that heavily influences how the layout would be coded.

Comment: I would love if the compass was moving down as the text come closer. Kind of like if the compass is a persons head and someone throw a apple towards that person.

as the apple come closer the person docks and the apple just misses the head.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the layout code, but have you considered instead changing the color of the compass so that the text is still legible when over the compass image?  For example, the compass could be a slightly different shade of the red background color.

Comment: I want to limit the amount of colours I use on the website. I like the minmalistic feel and I want that the reader only focus on contant, and less destraction will ahieve that goal.